# Unable to edit input field added via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple table with cells. When the user clicks on a cell, a textbox is added inside the cell where they can edit the content. However, when i double click a cell to edit it's content, the attributes of the input field show up. It does not allow me to edit and add another value. Here is the script I'm using.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var theads = document.getElementsByTagName("th");

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      highlightCell(i);
    });
  }

    function highlightCell(x) {
        var txtBox = document.createElement("input");
        txtBox.id = "myTxt";
        txtBox.type = "text";
            for (var i = 0; i<9; i++) {
              if (i == x) {
                txtBox.value = cells[i].innerHTML;

                cells[i].innerHTML = "";
                cells[i].appendChild(txtBox);
                cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This (txtBox.id = "myTxt";) is going to mean that every added element will have the same ID and therefore will not behave according to plan - you need to hae ead id be unique - just add the index to it to make the id unique for each added item.

Comment: Also I feel like its going to endlessly create inputs instead of focusing on the input you want...

Comment: @gavgrif, i made the id equal the index number but still get the same problem. The output when I try to edit is <input id="7" type="text"> when I click cell 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, just needed to use select(). This highlights the selected field, adds a input box which the user can update, then save the value in the cell when enter is pressed.

```
function highlightCell(x) {
  //add input field inside cell
  var txtBox = document.createElement("input");
  txtBox.id = x;
  txtBox.type = "text";

    for (var i = 0; i<9; i++) {
      if (i == x) {
        txtBox.value = cells[i].innerHTML;

        cells[i].innerHTML = "";
        cells[i].appendChild(txtBox);
        txtBox.select();

        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "lightBlue";

        cells[x].onkeypress = function(){
          var event = window.event;
          var btnPress = event.keyCode;

          if(btnPress == 13)
          {
            var elem = document.getElementById(x);
            cells[x].innerHTML = elem.value;
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
          }
        }
      } else {
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    }
  }
```